# Matplotlib - Create grid of subplot with 1:1 axis scale

Tags: matplotlib

Is there any way to create a plot like the one in figure below, having an axis scale of 1:1. By 1:1 I mean that if two ticks with values 100-200 have a distance on screen of 2cm on the x axis, it should be the same on the y axis. Instead as you can see in the figure, ticks on the  x axis are much larger. [image: plot]

Comment: When you find a answer that is helpful to you and answers your question, you may want to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/182943). Of course, [it is not an obligation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87767/accept-an-answer-obligation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ax.set_aspect('equal')` after the fact for each axis `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')` when you generate the axes.  [example/doc](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#make-the-aspect-ratio-for-plots-equal)